# Selenium: How to get text without clicking on tab?

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to find text that is located on a specific tab. For some reason the text is available in the html but when I use the command driver.find_element_by_id('hand-graph-title-overview').text without clicking on the 'Overview' tab it returns a empty string. However, when I do click on the 'Overview' tab it will return 'Unpaired OOP' successfully. Does anyone know how to get the text without clicking on the tab?

Images of what I'm trying to scrape.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nSc0.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyvDA.png

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. You can't access the element from the other tab without focusing on it. Retrieval of text is totally based on the presence of the element on the current page. When you click on tab then automatically it gets loaded in the dom and then only you can access the element.

Comment: I ended up just parsing the HTML code to grab the info I needed but thank you for the explanation about the DOM. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: Anytime my friend. So I believe that you are using JSoup for the parsing of HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and get the 'value' attribute of the element.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('hand-graph-title-overview').get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: I tried this and it returned the same result as the .text method but thanks for trying to help me out with this. Ended up just getting the HTML code and parsing through it.